# Using a fixedWindow of an unbouded datasource as side input for a parDo?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am reading data (GPS-coordinates, with time stamps) from a unbounded pub/sub datasource and need to calculate the distance between all those points. My idea is to have lets say 1 minute windows and do a ParDo with the whole collection as a side input, where I use the side input to look up the next point and calculate the distance inside the ParDo.

If I run the pipeline I can see the View.asList step is not producing any output. Also calcDistance is never producing any output. Are there any examples of how to use a FixedWindow collection as side input? [picture of pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xzqZ.png)

Pipeline:

```
PCollection<Timepoint> inputWindow = pipeline.apply(PubsubIO.Read.topic(""))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new ExtractTimestamps()))
                .apply(Window.<Timepoint>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1))));

final PCollectionView<List<Timepoint>> SideInputWindowed = inputWindow.apply(View.<Timepoint>asList());

inputWindow.apply(ParDo.named("Add Timestamp "+teams[i]).of(new AddTimeStampAsKey()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new CalcDistanceTest(SideInputWindowed)).withSideInputs(SideInputWindowed));
```

ParDo:

```
    static class CalcDistance extends DoFn<KV<String,Timepoint>,Timepoint> {
    private final PCollectionView<List<Timepoint>> pCollectionView;

    public CalcDistance(PCollectionView pCollectionView){
        this.pCollectionView = pCollectionView;
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("starting to calculate distance");
        Timepoint input = c.element().getValue();
        //doing distance calculation
        c.output(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall issue is that the timestamp of the element is not known by Dataflow when reading from Pubsub since for your usecase its an attribute of the data.

You'll want to ensure that when reading from Pubsub, you ingest the records with a timestamp label as [discussed here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#using-user-specified-timestamps).

Finally, the [GameStats example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/gaming-example#what-does-gamestats-do) uses a side input to find spammy users. In your case instead of calculating a **globalMeanScore per window**, you'll just place all your **Timepoints** into the side input.

Comment: Hi Lukas! Thanks for your tips, I really appreciate it . I did as you said and can see that it is working now and can use the sideinput now. Just my watermark is stuck but I think this is another question and I will open a different thread for it.